# Finding the depth of a specific node in a binary tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree

This is my code I have so far that simply finds the depth of the whole tree. How would I find the depth of just one node value (item)?

```
Template <typename T>
int stree<t>::nodeLevel(const T& item)
{
int depthLeft, depthRight, depthval;

if (t==NULL)
depthval = -1;

else
{
depthLeft = depth(t->left);
depthRight = depth(t->right);
depthval = 1+(depthLeft > depthRight ? DepthLeft : depthRight);
}
return depthval;
}
```

Comment: Well I would start by fixing that typo. Otherwise, just do it the same way you would implement `find` for T, but count recursion level instead of looking whether you found it or not.

Comment: `if(t==NULL) depthval = 0;` if tree is empty the height of tree will be 0 not -1.....

Comment: That piece of code will not compile. `Template`? `T` and `t`? The possible use of the template type used in a comparison?

Comment: Presumably `t` is `item`, except `item` is a reference (which can't be a null pointer) while apparently `t` is a pointer.

Comment: t is the root node of a tree. Item is a node value to search for.

Comment: @jarod42 I rolled back your edit, as it changed the meaning of the code. It's up to the OP to post meaningful and working code.

Comment: @HadeS - I don't think he's looking for overall tree depth, but actually the depth of a particular node (the one he is inputting to his routine).  That being said, returning a -1 could be VERY useful in determining if the input was NULL versus determining if the node input was actually the root node of the tree (dependent on how he assigns his leveling of course, if root level # is 0 or 1).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I considered these as 2 typo (case sensitive). But sure, OP may fix indentation and typo. @ user2105982, you may edit your question to fix indentation, typo, and add useful information given as comment (as `t` is root).

Comment: @trumpetlicks ... according to this code the height of tree with one node will be 0...and how does it matter if I pass NULL to this function or assign NULL to the root node and then pass it to the function.

Comment: @HadeS - The way I see understand the OPs "intent" is he is essentially passing in the node itself for which he wishes to get its depth value.  We don't know what node that is, whether it is somewhere deep in the tree or the root node, etc...  That being said, (if I am correct), then the return of a -1 could signify to the USER of the routine whether it is the root node (at level 0) versus the passing in of NULL to the routine (a -1).  Kinda depends on what the OP really wants, kinda not well defined :-)  Both valid points considering the info given at this point!

Answer (score 0):

The depth can be counted as you traverse the tree.  If you begin at the top (root node) with either a depth of 0 or 1 (dependent on your true definition of the base is), then you increment your depth count, every time you have to move downward to a left or right node, and decrement every time you move back to that particular nodes parent node.

Comment: It is perhaps best to pass the current depth as an argument to be returned when the item is found. Cuts down the maintenance on depth (just call `find(ptr, item, depth + 1)` on each branch), less space for errors ;-)